# Netflix install issue

Tags: netflix

I know this has been dealt with extensively but I have an issue I can not find an answer for. I am trying to install the netflix desktop app and in the terminal after entering the last step "sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop" I get an error that says "unable to locate package netflix-desktop"

I would really appreciate some help, thanks,

John

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`after adding the PPA?

Comment: That package is [indeed not available in Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=netflix-desktop&searchon=names&suite=raring&section=all). Please link to the post with the instructions to install this package. It will probably also instruct you to add a PPA or other type of repository first. And you seem to have skipped that.

Comment: Here is the link, sorry it took so long to get back to you guys but I did not see my notification (noob mistake). http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html

Comment: And yes I did run sudo apt-get update

Comment: Well I've got it working now, I ran those three steps again from the link I posted and went through a bunch of other things accepting and approving downloads and eventually it all came together. Thanks for your replys.

Answer (score 0):

Netflix requires Microsoft Silverlight plugin with DRM (Digital Rights Management). Even thought there is a native Linux program similar to Silverlight is Moonlight, Moonlight does support DRM so it does not help.

You will have to add PPA (Personal Packages Archives) in order to install Netflix on Linux.

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
```

To install Netflix Desktop on Ubuntu and Linux Mint

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

Source: [How to install Netflix on Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Fedora](http://namhuy.net/1867/how-to-install-netflix-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-fedora.html)